# Can't install PyTorch 1.7.0

Tags: python, installation, pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory

I need to install these four packages (to run [this code](https://github.com/kris927b/SkillSpan)):

```
!pip install allennlp==1.3
!pip install transformers==4.0.0
!pip install torch==1.7.0
!pip install networkx
```

These commands work in a Jupyter Notebook, but I need to use a GPU for this project. When I run it in Google Colab, Kaggle Kernel, and Deepnote, I get this error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.7.0 (from versions: 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.7.0

Running these (suggested by [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66858277/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-torch-1-7-0cpu)) still produces an error:

```
!pip install torch==1.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html 
!pip install torch==1.8.0+cu111 torchvision==0.9.0+cu111 torchaudio==0.8.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I also tried the proxy fix from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52328655/pip-cant-install-any-package), but none of the 30 proxies I tried worked.

How can I install PyTorch 1.7.0 on a platform that provides free GPU access?

Comment: what's your python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider updating your Python version on Colab to an older one (3.8 for example),

I tried Python 3.8 and it worked fine .

See :

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68530310/18963373) is the method that I followed to update the versio.

Comment: Thank you, this fixes it! However, I'm now running into a new issue with jsonnet that prevents me from installing allennlip 1.3:
  Building wheels for collected packages: jsonnet
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error 
  Installing collected packages: jsonnet
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  Running setup.py install for jsonnet ... error
  error: legacy-install-failure
  
  I've tried the fixes I found in stack overflow and github, but they didn't work. For the full context, here is my colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-DAOTc0EUgrgbuQr5XDVQYCHrPWrwQLi?usp=sharing

Comment: I think it would be better to accept the answer and close this question , then create s new question with details about the new error

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77774811/unable-to-install-jsonnet-in-google-colab-notebook-failed-building-wheel) is the new question